# Why did Lizzie think the walkers were still human?

Tags: the-walking-dead, zombie

In *The Walking Dead*, Lizzie is taken care of by Carol after her dad's death.

But what I don't get is why Lizzie thinks that the walkers are still human. She is feeding them and is hurt whenever someone kills one. But you can clearly tell they are not human anymore.

So is it something she believes or is she just crazy?

Comment: #justlookattheflowers lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She's crazy.  She's so crazy that she kills her sister - and almost kills Judith - and has to be "put down" to keep the baby safe.

> Tyreese:  So what do we do?
>
> Carol:  I could leave with her.
>
> Tyreese:  What?
>
> Carol:  We can't sleep with her and Judith under the same roof.
>
> Tyreese:  You wouldn't make it. Not on your own.
>
> Carol:  She can't be around other people.
>
> Tyreese:  Maybe we could try to help her. Talk her back somehow.
>
> Carol:  This is how she is. It was already there. I didn't see it.
>
> Tyreese:  How could you?
>
> Carol: I should have seen it.
>
> Tyreese:  So maybe we go. Me and Judith.
>
> Carol:  You won't make it either. She can't be around other people.

However, thinking that zombies might be people doesn't necessarily mean you're crazy - after all, Hershel and Milton, among others, have felt the same way.

Comment: I remember that. Haha Rich would have killed someone if Judith died. Lol. Thank you for answering! :). Have a good night. @WadCheber